# How to absolute position a text on a button programatically in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

How can I absolute position a text on a button in android programatically(Defining Dynamically in Activity)

For Ex :
[image]

When I reduce the size of a button the text gets shrink ed which results in an additional height , so whether can I make the text (button text) to overflow so that 90% come in a single line even if the 90% comes out of the button it is fine but should get the value or can I add a textView and absolute position it with respect to button how can I achieve either of these dynamically whether is it possible?

Some Sample Code how I got the result

```
<LinearLayout
                        android:weightSum="1.0"
                        android:layout_weight=".75"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:background="#ffef1128"
                        >


                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/textbox12"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.01"
                            android:layout_width="0dip"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:text="1%"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:background="@color/fund_background_blue"
                            android:textColor="@color/gen_text_color"
                             />


                         </LinearLayout>
```

So the buttons width is 1% and the text I'm trying to display is getting inside the width of the button which makes it invisible as that is the normal behavior of wrapping the content but I want the text to be displayed horizontally even if the text overflows after the button it is ok want to know the best possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
This could help?

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnFindMe" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/findme"></ImageButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

A View's minimum height and minimum with depends on its childView's height and width. thats why when you reduce the size of a button the text gets shrink which results in an additional height. If you want to to shrink it then you have to add a HorizontalScrollView and add TextView inside HorizontalScrollView.

Or you can try-

```
    android:singleLine="true"
```

and to set absolute position of x you can try to set text view left align to Superview and set left margin of textView. at runtime -

so to set leftalign-

```
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

and to set left margin-

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams();
// work as x absolute position
rlp.leftMargin = x;
```